# How to use Union Types in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, union-types

I'm using typescript on a project and in some parts of it I have to use union types. But I'm getting some weird error messages that I don't know how to deal with.
Consider the type below:

```
type body = {
  [_: string]:
    | 'boolean'
    | 'number'
    | 'string'
    | {
        type: 'boolean' | 'number' | 'string'
        optional?: boolean
      }
    | {
        type: 'array'
        items: 'boolean' | 'string' | 'number'
        optional?: boolean
        [_: string]: any
      }
}
```

I'm using `[_: string]:` because I should be able to use any arbitrary key. The value can either be a string indicating a type or can be a object that provides more details.
Now consider the following function:

```
function show(data: body) {
  console.log(data)
}
```

When I call the above function with the object below:

```
const data = {
  username: { type: 'string', optional: false },
  address: { type: 'string' },
  city: 'string'
}
```

Typescript gives the error below:

> Argument of type '{ username: { type: string; optional: boolean; }; address: { type: string; }; city: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'body'.

> Property 'username' is incompatible with index signature.

> Type '{ type: string; optional: boolean; }' is not assignable to type '"string" | "number" | "boolean" | { type: "string" | "number" | "boolean"; optional?: boolean | undefined; } | { [_: string]: any; type: "array"; items: "string" | "number" | "boolean"; optional?: boolean | undefined; }'.

> Property 'items' is missing in type '{ type: string; optional: boolean; }' but required in type '{ [_: string]: any; type: "array"; items: "string" | "number" | "boolean"; optional?: boolean | undefined; }'.

How can I solve this?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is with an overly broad inference on the type of the `data` variable. Take a look at the [reproduction here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=12&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBARg9gExFAvFA3gKClA2gfQC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwF1DscoAfKAcnjgBsIBDah2Y52HagFcAtjAjlhLNpzJU6CluyyLFoSMS5xeAoUvHTZ80ypq112qHDDBKcavx4B%20Ytz6CRLAF9-TX8dcAh9fnJyfhA7bUpgCCkSfR9jDisKG0yxSRk5eMVHZ1d3L1hDX2pQlgJiazpGKEEQWqCgzAAzCWoAY1LqUgALOAB3AAoEfmB%20b0QQAEoMZj7XEiMAOh44WimZ-kXMTrXqMihp2dQVnAkSOTcpCIwoXWeORtsAGgcnFzceMQuu57lAAl9mPwEAhyBASKkXm99J9MuDVokQMjsmpjphMCRRpNLocANyYIA).

If you hover your `data` variable, you'll note that it was given the inferred type:

```
{
    username: {
        type: string;
        optional: boolean;
    };
    address: {
        type: string;
    };
    city: string;
}
```

Breaking down your error message, we see the first line:

> Property 'username' is incompatible with index signature.

Indicates that `username` is the issue here. As you can see from the inferred type, that property has the type `{type: string, optional: boolean}`.

You might think that this would match to the

`{ type: 'boolean' | 'number' | 'string', optional?: boolean }`

part of your union, however the critical difference is that this part of your union requires the `type` property to have one of the *literal string types* `'boolean' | 'number' | 'string'`, and *does not permit* any string (represented by the type `string` (without quotes)).

This is why it then tries to match to the final piece of your union, which would allow the `type: string` key/value pair due to the index signature. But this last part of the union also requires an `Items` property which is what is leading to the specific error you see.

---

So how do you fix it? Well you need to give typescript a hint that the `username.type` property of your `data` object is not just any string. Here are some various ways:

- Use an explicit declaration or cast, using the `body` type, as in Andreas' excellent answer.
- Cast just that property's value: `type: 'string' as 'string'`. You'd have to do this for all three properties so this is not very ideal in this particular case.
- Declare the entire object as a const: `const data = { ... } as const`
- Or just use the object inline instead of declaring it first:

```
show({
  username: { type: 'string', optional: false },
  address: { type: 'string' },
  city: 'string'
});
```

Comment: For future readers, if you want more information on why the type of `data.username.type` is _widened_ to `string`, you can check out [this explanation of _literal widening_](https://sandersn.github.io/manual/Widening-and-Narrowing-in-Typescript.html#literal-widening). TL;DR: Because `data` is mutable, it widens the types of any literals to their more general primitive type.

Answer (score 4):

You can explictly declare what type your property `data` is

```
const data: body = {
  username: { type: 'string', optional: false },
  address: { type: 'string' },
  city: 'string'
}
```

or cast it

```
const data = {
  username: { type: 'string', optional: false },
  address: { type: 'string' },
  city: 'string'
} as body;
```