# Typescript: How to make a client aware of the exact returned type, when calling a factory that uses a typeguard?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have two different classes:

```
class Car{
    drive(){
        console.log('Driving!')
    }
}

class Plane{
    fly(){
        console.log('Flying!')
    }
}
```

And then there is a simple factory, that returns a different object, based on the string provided:

```
type PossibleObjects = 'car' | 'plane';

function vehicleFactory(wantedObject:PossibleObjects){

    if(wantedObject === 'car')return new Car()
    
    if(wantedObject === 'plane')return new Plane()

    return new Car()//Just to avoid undefined
}
```

When I call this factory, Typescript doesn't seem to recognize the specific object that was returned:

```
const bmw = vehicleFactory('car')//Would expect Typescript to infer the resulted object from now on.
bmw.drive()//Error: Property 'drive' does not exist on type 'Car | Plane'. Property 'drive' does not exist on type 'Plane'.
```

Even though "vehicleFactory" is clearly called with "car" argument, Typescript doesn't recognize any method on "bmw", because Car and Plane do not share this method.

Is there any way to overcome this, and make TS aware of the specific object returned?

Comment: [Function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) allow you to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @Etheryte said, you need to use function overloadings:

```js
class Car {
  drive() {
    console.log('Driving!')
  }
}

class Plane {
  fly() {
    console.log('Flying!')
  }
}

function vehicleFactory(wantedObject: 'car'): Car
function vehicleFactory(wantedObject: 'plane'): Plane
function vehicleFactory(wantedObject: string): Car
function vehicleFactory(wantedObject: string) {

  if (wantedObject === 'car') return new Car()

  if (wantedObject === 'plane') return new Plane()

  return new Car()//Just to avoid undefined
}

const car = vehicleFactory('car') // Car
const plane = vehicleFactory('plane') // Plane
const any = vehicleFactory('any') // Car
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZ41Kw)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a generic type and make the return type depend on the generic param instead of on the actual result. This approach helps the consumers of your function, but doesn't protect your function itself:

```js
type PlaneOrCar<T extends PossibleObjects> = T extends 'plane'
  ? Plane : Car;

type PlaneOrCarPar<T extends PossibleObjects> = T extends 'plane'
  ? 'plane' : 'car';
```

Then you can use it like this:

```js
function vehicleFactory<T extends PossibleObjects>(
    wantedObject: PlaneOrCarPar<T>): PlaneOrCar<T> {
    if(wantedObject === 'car') return new Car() as any;
    if(wantedObject === 'plane') return new Plane() as any;
    return new Car() as any;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try explicitly casting the Type.

```js
const bmw = vehicleFactory('car') as Car;
```

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67909863/15407577

Or if you'd rather change the design of your classes you could create a parent class that is implemented differently by the sub-classes. Something like below.

```js
abstract class Vehicle {
       abstract move(): any
}

class Plane extends Vehicle {
       move() {
           console.log('Flying!');
       }
}
class Car extends Vehicle {
       move() {
           console.log('Driving!');
       }
}

type PossibleObjects = 'car' | 'plane';
function vehicleFactory(wantedObject: PossibleObjects): Vehicle {
       switch (wantedObject) {
              case 'car': {
                     return new Car()
              }
              case 'plane': {
                     return new Plane();
              }
       }
}
const bmw = vehicleFactory('car');
bmw.move();
```